# Merge two int column data into one using Entity Framework 6.x

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this type of data stored in my database table.

below is my sql query.

```
select distinct firstuser, seconduser from [mytable] where firstuser=1 or seconduser=1
```

how can I merge this two column value into a single column using entity framework?

for example 1,4,5,2,3 like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want this.

```
var data = (from b in (from a in myTable
                        where a.firstuser == 1 || a.seconduser  == 1
                        select new[]{a.firstuser,a.seconduser } )            
             from c in b
             select c).Distinct().ToList();
```

this will give you list of integers the way you want it

In method syntax it would be

```
    var data = myTable.Where (a => a.firstuser  == 1 || a.seconduser == 1 )
                      .Select (a => new[]{ a.firstuser ,a.seconduser  } )                         
                      .SelectMany (a => a )
                      .Distinct()
                      .ToList();
```

Comment: yes, may be something like this. I'll try and let you know if it works as expected. and how can I convert this linq query to extension query?

Comment: Many thanks. I have posted an another answer for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Add 'AS'

```
SELECT DISTINCT firstuser || '|' || seconduser AS USERS FROM [mytable] WHERE firstuser=1 or seconduser=1
```

`||` are used to concatenate the string that will be displayed under column "USERS"

Comment: I don't want to concat two columns values.

Comment: I don't understand what your asking "for example 1,4,5,2,3 like this".. please provide a better example

Comment: I want to merge two int columns into a single column column. look in image.
there is two columns firstuser and seconduser.
seconduser column values will merged in firstuser column. using entity framework.

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = myTable
             .Where(x=>x.firstuser==1 || x.seconduser==1)
             .SelectMany(x=> new List<int>()
             { 
                 x.firstuser,
                 x.seconduser
             }).Distinct()
             .ToList();
```

you can achieve same thing using this query.